# hdf5 made with h5py py2 corrupted after opening with h5py in py3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, corruption, h5py

### Problem

I have a file created with h5py in python 2.7.

These steps lead to a corruption:

1. I download a fresh copy of it from a collaborator using `scp`. It is whole and 286MB.
2. I check that it is readable by opening it with `hdfview`. This shows all the datasets and groups properly.
3. I exit hdfview.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 to ensure `hdfview` is not corrupting the file.
5. I open ipython 3.6 and,

   `import h5py
   f = h5py.File(filename,'r')
   g = f['/sol000']#one group that should be there`

I get `KeyError: "Unable to open object (Object 'sol000' doesn't exist)"`

6. I `f.close()` and exit ipython. I again open it with `hdfview` and the entire structure is gone. The file is now 4KB.

I am able to open the file in python 2 hdf5 and access all the datasets, but must use python 3 for my code.

### Systems

File created on Fedora 24 64-bit, python 2.7, hdf5 2.7.0

System trying to read it on Fedora 25 64-bit python 3.6, h5py 2.7.0

### Minimal code showing should work

On system 1:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
f = h5py.File("file.hdf5","w")
f.create_dataset("/sol000/data",(100,100),dtype=float)
f["/sol000/data"] = np.zeros([100,100],dtype=float)
f.close()
```

On system 2: Do steps 1-4.

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File("file.hdf5","r")
f.visit(lambda *x:print(x))
#(sol000/data,)
f.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a simple hdf5 file with the one (from scratch) and opening with the other? Along the lines of [mcve]. Can there be unicode strings inside?

Comment: I have a second hdf5 file from the collaborator and it works fine. However, I'm asking him if a different combination of python/h5py was used to create it. If the same versions were used then it fulfills the minimal verifiable criteria.

Comment: If it's not copy-pasteable from your question, it's not an MCVE.

Comment: I've added this now.

Comment: Your edit suggests that this example works. We _expect_ it to work. You need a reproducible example that breaks; that's the C in MCVE.

Comment: Indeed, I was following you advice and tried creating a simple hdf5 file with the one (from scratch) and opening with the other. I am unable to access the system it was created on unfortunately. Thanks for your assistance and advice though.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad you figured out how to fix it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to enforce `libver=earliest`. I.e. the following code worked to open the file:

```
import h5py
f = f.File("file.hdf5","r",libver="earliest")
```

I've discovered a possible inconsistency in h5py documentation.
[It claims](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/file.html#version-bounding) that

> The “earliest” option means that HDF5 will make a best effort to be
>   backwards compatible.
>
> The default is “earliest”.

This can't be true if it only works when I explicitly set it.
My collaborator, it turns out, created the corruptable file with an older version of hdf5 C library.